# Flutter: How can I implement this type of bottom sheet in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want this type of Cupertino modal bottom sheet?

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
Chrome - develop for the web
Android Studio (version 2022.2)
VS Code (version 1.79.2)
Connected device (4 available)
Network resources

[image: Ios Cupertino Modal Bottom Sheet]

modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.1.2 this package is not working with flutter 3.10.5

https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

Comment: You just use showModalBottomSheet in flutter package. See the [officail document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package which worked for me. https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel
In the body, I am returning a Stack which contains two widgets: The one behind the panel (Container) and the panel itself as below.

```
 body: Stack(
      children:[
        Container(), // set the contents behind the panel
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SlidingUpPanel(
             color: Colors.white, //set the panel color
             minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2, //set min height
             maxHeight: 750, // set desired max height when expanded
             borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only( // border decorations
                 topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0),
                 topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
               ),
             panel: Column(...), // contents of the panel
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can call showModalBottomSheet from any stateful or stateless widget providing the context, this one comes in the material part of flutter, no need to use extra packages

```
 showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: builder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Packages to get this done.

- [modal_bottom_sheet: 3.0.0-pre](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet/versions/3.0.0-pre) (The stable version do not support latest versions of the flutter)
- [cupertino_modal_sheet](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_modal_sheet)

##### Demo:

| modal_bottom_sheet | cupertino_modal_sheet |
| --- | --- |
| [image: modal_bottom_sheet] | [image: cupertino_modal_sheet] |

Comment: Another package that I found recently: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cupernino_bottom_sheet